# Big-O Constants Rule Question for not-monotonically non-decreasing functions

Tags: asymptotics

I know that for positive monotonically non-decreasing functions, f(n) and g(n),

```
f(n) = O(g(n) + c) entails
f (n) = O(g(n))
```

Why does this always true only for positive monotonically non-decreasing functions?

If there exists one, give a counter-example that shows that the above Big O rule is not necessarily true for functions that are not monotonically non-decreasing.

I'm really confused why the rule specifies only positive, monotonic, non-decreasing functions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(n)= 1$ and $g(n)= 1/n$ then $f(n) = O(g(n) +1)$ but $f(n)$ is not a $O(g(n))$.

So you see that some condition is needed.

To say it *only* holds for  for positive monotonically non-decreasing functions is not completely precise, as there are other $g$ where it also holds true, for exaple it would be true for $g(n)= 10 + n + 3(-1)^n$.

To see it does hold under the conditions you gave note that $g(n) \ge g(1)$. 
So you can say $g(n)+ C \le g(n)+ (C/g(1)) g(1) \le g(n) (1 + C/g(1))$.

So if $|f(n)| \le D (g(n) + C) $ for some $D$, then $|f(n)| \le (D (1 + C/g(1)) )g(n)$. This yields the claim.

Comment: but isn't f(n) = 1 a monotonically non-decreasing function? Is there an example that isn't a monotonically non-decreasing function?

Comment: Yes, $f(n)$ is but $g(n)$ is not. If you want an example where both violate the consdtion take $f(n)=1/n$ and $g(n)=1/n^2$.

Comment: So it's correct that if f(n) = 1/n and g(n) = 1/n^2, 

f(n) = O(g(n) + 2) but not true that f(n) = O(g(n))?

Comment: Yes this is the case.